# new and delete on different scope

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

Consider the following code:

```
int *expand_array(int *old_arr,int array_length)
{
    int *new_arr = new int[array_length +3];
    for(int counter=0;counter<array_length;counter++)
    new_arr[counter]=old_arr[counter];

    delete[] old_arr;
    return new_arr;
}

int main()
{
     int *my_first_arr = new int[4];
     int *my_expanded_arr=expand_array(my_first_arr,4);
     delete[] my_expanded_arr;
 }
```

will there be any memory leak here?
And to generalize the question, 
if the pointer returned from a new statement is copied ,passed to a function or assigned to a different pointer, will the delete copied_pointer release the memory?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is perfectly valid C++ and has no memory leaks. You can copy a pointer as often as you want to and `delete`ing any of those copies in any scope has the same effect.

It is still bad practice, however, and you shouldn't write code like this. Use of raw `new` and `delete` is too error prone and will make for poorly maintainable code. Instead, use RAII wrapper types like `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` or, in this case, `std::vector`.

The code in your question is basically equivalent to this.

```
int
main()
{
  auto numbers = std::vector<int>(4);
  numbers.resize(7);
}
```

Much simple, no?

Comment: "*Your code is perfectly valid C++ and has no memory leaks.*" If `new int[array_length +3];` throws then `my_first_arr` will surely leak, no?

Comment: It will “leak” but in this case the program will be terminated anyway. But it is true that the code is not composeable in an exception-safe way.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you believe that there would be a memory leak? Of course there wouldn't be.

But there is a different bug in this code. If the new array size is larger than the size of the existing `old_arr`, the code that copies the old array to the newly allocated `int` array is going to copy too much, run off past the end of the old array, resulting in undefined behavior; possibly a crash (old array size is 2 ints, array_length is 10, the for loop will attempt to copy 10 values from the old array which only has 2).

Comment: I don't think "of course" is a useful response to a code review request. Though whether such a request is on-topic here is another matter.

Comment: thanx. I had i doubt about delete requiring the original pointer returned from new -and only that one- to delete the dynamically allocated memory.
And ofc there could be an array size check before proceeding with the copying code.

Comment: @ParakmiI `delete behaves like a function that takes its parameter by value. It only cares what value and type you pass to it.